# How to use async await in for loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, async-await

Basically I have a function which loops through all the elements from an api and pushes it to a array and then I return the array, but I am getting random of amount of elements everytime I run this function.

```js
function getElements() {
    const url = "https://neelpatel05.pythonanywhere.com/element/atomicnumber?atomicnumber=";
    var elements = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=118;i++){
        newurl = url+i.toString();
        fetch(newurl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => elements.push(data.symbol))
    }
    return elements;
}
console.log(getElements());
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `how to use async/await` you are asking the right question, you are on the right track. Have you tried it?

Comment: well i did learn about it but i dont how to  implement them in the loop

Comment: BTW it's weird that you get a "random of amount of elements" in your array. According to this code, you should get exactly 0 element, because you return the array immediately, before it is filled by your... 118 concurrent asynchronous calls

Comment: i have no idea also i am javascript beginner so i dont know much about async and await

Comment: You did learn about it, so give it a try :) If you did learn about it, surely you can try and start to write something? I don't want to simply give you the solution on a plate, because I believe you are nearly there and you can do it with what you already know.

Comment: u can try the code ans see for yourself

Comment: Hello there is lot of documentation and question about it, please do your search before asking a question. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: ok i will try it out thank you so muhc for the reply

Comment: I did try the code, and as expected it gives me exactly `[]`. It can't be otherwise, because synchronous code executes before asynchronous code.

Comment: You are missing 2 keywords: `async` and `await`

Comment: Yes and removing `.then()` because that's what is messing up with your result

Answer (score 1):

You need to push entire promise to array and wait for them all to be resolved, so they will be resolved in parallel.

```js
function getElements() {
    const url = "https://neelpatel05.pythonanywhere.com/element/atomicnumber?atomicnumber="
    const elements = []
    for(let i=1;i <= 118; i++){
        newurl = url + i // no need to 'i.toString()'
        elements.push( // push entire promise, not just "unpacked" response
          fetch(newurl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => data.symbol)
        )
    }
    return Promise.all(elements)
}

getElements().then(elements => {
  console.log(elements.length)
  console.log(elements)
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: yesh i tried this and got this working but it take a hell lot of time to complete is there a way i can make it take less time ?

Comment: Yurgh no, this is ugly. You are mixing the `async/await` and the `.then()` syntaxes. It eventually works, so I won't downvote, but man is this inelegant

Comment: Yes, do not send 118 requests in a loop.

Comment: Or don't await each request and send them parallel?

Comment: then what is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: Ok, give me 2 mins. I just wanted you to show how to make your code works, not to CR and improve.

Comment: @Amey patil, send request in batches, like wait for 10 promise to finish, then next 10, so on...

Comment: `it take a hell lot of time to complete is there a way i can make it take less time ?` first, don't make 118 concurrent calls, give the server some time to breathe. Then, the results will always be the same (you are querying a periodic table) so do this once, store the results in a variable and reuse them.

Comment: @Ameypatil now it should work fine, but as Jeremy said, it's constant date that won't change, you can simply store it in your app. Also I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it in 1 request instead of 118 (look at the doc).

Answer (score 1):

All the promises stored in `elements` will resolve together using `Promise.all()` method.

```
function getElements() {
    const url = "https://neelpatel05.pythonanywhere.com/element/atomicnumber?atomicnumber=";
    var elements = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=118;i++){
        newurl = url+i.toString();
        const res = fetch(newurl)
        .then(response => response.json());
        elements.push(res);
    }
    return Promise.all(elements);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not send so many request at a same time, send request in batches...
Wait for 10 promise to finish, then next 10, then next 10, so on...

```js
async function getElements() {
    const url = "https://neelpatel05.pythonanywhere.com/element/atomicnumber?atomicnumber=";
    let elements = [], pending = [];
    for(let i=1; i <= 118; i++){
        let p = fetch(url + i)
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(data => elements.push(data.symbol))
           .catch(console.log);
         
        if (pending.push(p) > 10) {
            await Promise.all(pending);
            pending = [];
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(pending).then(() => elements);
}

// you cannot use async await in global scope, so I used 'then' here instead
getElements().then(elements => console.log(elements.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here you go then (I have limited the number of calls to 3, to not hammer this poor server too much)

```js
const url = "https://neelpatel05.pythonanywhere.com/element/atomicnumber?atomicnumber=";

const getElements = async () => {
    let elements = [];

    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
        newurl = url+i.toString();

        const response = await fetch(newurl);
        const data = await response.json()
        
        elements.push(data.symbol)
    }
    return elements; // This is a Promise of array, not an array, because an async function always returns a Promise of something. So this can be awaited.
};

(async () => {
    console.log(await getElements());
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send all requests at once and store the promises in an array. Then you can wait for all promises to resolve:

```js
async function getElements() {
    const url = "https://neelpatel05.pythonanywhere.com/element/atomicnumber?atomicnumber=";
    const promises = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=118;i++){
        newurl = url+i.toString();
        promises.push(fetch(newurl));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
(async () => {
    const responses = await getElements();
    responses.forEach(async response => console.log(await response.json()));
})();
```

A server should be able to handle 118 requests at once but you shouldn't send too many requests.

Be aware that in this minimal example the order of the console.log usually is not the order you sent the requests. `forEach` doesn't consider `await`s.

Comment: `await` doesn't work inside array methods like `.forEach` or `.map`.

Comment: @JeremyThille Of course, it works. Press "Run code snippet" and see how it awaits `response.json()`.

Comment: [No it doesn't](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/ExWXjKa).

Comment: @JeremyThille When I press "Run code snippet" I get 118 objects. It may not work on your platform for some reasons but usually it works. jsfiddle supports it: see https://jsfiddle.net/nzh4d1e3/ and wait about 5 seconds

Comment: It works but doesn't do what you think it does. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @JeremyThille It does exactly what I think and I mentioned it in my answer in the last paragraph. You could use Array#map and some other logic to keep the order. It's just a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal rule of using `async` and `await` is that `await` can be used in an `async` function. So if you don't care about parallelism, you can just wrap your entire test into a bigger `async` function, add the keywords here and there, and that's it:

```js
async function main() {                  // <-- wrapper
    async function getElements() {       // <-- became async, so can use await
        const url = "https://neelpatel05.pythonanywhere.com/element/atomicnumber?atomicnumber=";
        var elements = [];
        for(var i=1;i<=118;i++){
            newurl = url+i.toString();
            await fetch(newurl)          // <-- await request right in the loop
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => elements.push(data.symbol))
        }
        return elements;
    }
    console.log(await getElements());    // <-- await the async function
}
main();                                  // <-- call wrapper
console.log("! results will come after this line !"); // memo about the test still being async
```